# how to start VNC service remotely without first logging into Ubuntu 12.04 locally

Tags: 12.04, vnc, vino

I tried the answers other similar queuest in Ask Ubuntu, but didn't get it to work.

I reboot Ubuntu 12.04.
I remote in using SSH, and do
`/usr/lib/vino/vino-server`
to start VNC service.

UltraVNC client reports: `Failed to connect to server!`

But if I login at the Ubuntu computer and try UltraVNC again, it works.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue. I tried user1689961's answer but got a connection refused. When I added the `-allow <ip address of client>` option, it worked.

The full command:

```
sudo x11vnc -safer -localhost -once -nopw -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -display :0 -allow <ip address>
```